# Replacing an iOS app already running

Tags: ios

Hi is it possible to replace an iOS app that is in production / active in the marketplace with a completely new application that was written ground up?

How does the upgrade process work? Does the user go through a normal app update process?

Comment: if it is of same bundle identifier an name then it is an normal update

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "replacing" the app?